# Using Calendar.monthdatescalendar() & Labor Day

Tags: python, calendar, python-datetime

I'm using Calendar and monthdatescalendar()

```
import Calendar

mycal = calendar.Calendar(0)
laborday = mycal.monthdatescalendar(2003, 9)[0][0]
```

correctly returns 09/01/2003

```
laborday = mycal.monthdatescalendar(2004, 9)[0][0]
```

returns 08/30/2014 which is **not** the desired result

What is the right way to correctly get FIRST ***day of the month (for any month/year) without getting the last ***day of the prior month instead because you get the first week correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Find the date for the first Monday after a given a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558535/python-find-the-date-for-the-first-monday-after-a-given-a-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `monthdatescalendar` returns *full weeks*, so will include prior months if needed to pad the first week out.

To get the correct day, you'll need to check against the month of the first Monday `datetime` object and choose the following Monday if required.

```
import calendar

def getLaborDay(year):
    month = 9
    mycal = calendar.Calendar(0)
    cal = mycal.monthdatescalendar(year, month)
    if cal[0][0].month == month:
        return cal[0][0]
    else:
        return cal[1][0]

print getLaborDay(2003)
print getLaborDay(2004)
```

[Gives:](http://codepad.org/9BzYcsT5)

```
2003-09-01
2004-09-06
```