# Get end of week based on date column

Tags: python, pandas

in the dataframe below, the 'end_of_week' column does not yet exist. I'm trying to make so that if 'date' is lesser or equal to Thursday of that week, 'end_of_week' is Thursday. How do I do this?

What I'm trying to do:

```
df['end_of_week'] = Thursday of same week if df['date'] <= Thursday
```

Example:

```
0   date    end_of_week
1   2015-08-31  2015-09-03 #if <= Thursday of that week
2   2015-09-01  2015-09-03
3   2015-09-07  2015-09-10
4   2015-09-09  2015-09-10
5   2015-09-16  2015-09-17
6   2015-09-17  2015-09-17
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
df['end_of_week'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: next_weekday(x, 3) if  x.weekday() < 3 else x)
```

where, from @phihag's answer at [Find the date for the first Monday after a given a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558535/python-find-the-date-for-the-first-monday-after-a-given-a-date):

```
def next_weekday(d, weekday):
    days_ahead = weekday - d.weekday()
    if days_ahead <= 0:
        days_ahead += 7
    return d + datetime.timedelta(days_ahead)
```

Doing a test:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
xl3 = pd.ExcelFile('test2.xlsx')
df3 = xl3.parse("Sheet1")
df3
Out[71]: 
   x          y       date 
0  1        fum 2015-06-01  
1  2         fo 2015-06-02 
2  3         fi 2015-06-03 
3  4        fee 2015-06-04 
4  5  dumbledum 2015-06-05 
5  6  dumbledee 2015-06-06 

df3['end_of_week'] = df3['date'].map(lambda x: next_weekday(x, 3) if x.weekday() < 3 else x)

df3
   x          y       date end_of_week 
0  1        fum 2015-06-01  2015-06-04
1  2         fo 2015-06-02  2015-06-04
2  3         fi 2015-06-03  2015-06-04
3  4        fee 2015-06-04  2015-06-04
4  5  dumbledum 2015-06-05  2015-06-05
5  6  dumbledee 2015-06-06  2015-06-06
```

Comment: Thank you!! this totally worked. You answer like all of the questions I ask!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) to find the nearest Thursday. Arrow considers Monday the zeroth day of the week.

```
import arrow

THURSDAY = 3
arw = arrow.get("2015-08-31")
arw = arw.replace(days= +(THURSDAY - arw.weekday())).format('YYYY-MM-DD')

#=> arw = '2015-09-03'
```

To address your issue directly:

```
import arrow

THURSDAY = 3
dates = [
    "2015-08-31",
    "2015-09-01",
    "2015-09-07",
    "2015-09-09",
    "2015-09-16",
    "2015-09-17",
]

end_of_week_dates = []

for date in dates:
    arw = arrow.get(date)
    if arw.weekday() <= THURSDAY:
        end_of_week = arw.replace(days= +(THURSDAY - arw.weekday())).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        end_of_week_dates.append(end_of_week)
    else:
        # handle the case where the date is after the Thursday of that week

# end_of_week_dates = [
#   '2015-09-03',
#   '2015-09-03',
#   '2015-09-10',
#   '2015-09-10',
#   '2015-09-17',
#   '2015-09-17'
# ]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I went to Tris' answer above