# first date of week greater than x

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get the ***first*** monday in july that is greater than July 10th for a list of dates, and i am wondering if there's an elegant solution that avoids for loops/list comprehension.
Here is my code so far that gives all july mondays greater than the 10th:

```
import pandas as pd
last_date = '08-Jul-2016'
monday2_dates=pd.date_range('1-Jan-1999',last_date, freq='W-MON') 
g1=pd.DataFrame(1.0, columns=['dummy'], index=monday2_dates) 
g1=g1.loc[(g1.index.month==7) & (g1.index.day>=10)]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558535/python-find-the-date-for-the-first-monday-after-a-given-a-date

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do it this way:

get list of 2nd Mondays within specified date range

```
In [116]: rng = pd.date_range('1-Jan-1999',last_date, freq='WOM-2MON')
```

filter them so that we will have only those in July with `day >= 10`

```
In [117]: rng = rng[(rng.month==7) & (rng.day >= 10)]
```

create a corresponding DF

```
In [118]: df = pd.DataFrame({'dummy':[1] * len(rng)}, index=rng)

In [119]: df
Out[119]:
            dummy
1999-07-12      1
2000-07-10      1
2003-07-14      1
2004-07-12      1
2005-07-11      1
2006-07-10      1
2008-07-14      1
2009-07-13      1
2010-07-12      1
2011-07-11      1
2014-07-14      1
2015-07-13      1
```

Comment: @NickD1, did that help?