# Python: date from plaintext (foreign language) weekday

Tags: python, date, weekday

I am looking to retrieve the next possible date for a weekday contained in a string. Complexity being that this weekday will be in foreign language (sv_SE).

In bash I can solve this using `dateround´:

```
startdate=$(dateround --from-locale=sv_SE -z CET today $startday)
```

Highly appreciate your guidance on how to solve this in Python.

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you provide an example date in that language?

Comment: "Onsdag" for example, but 4d11s answer below solves my problem

Answer (score 2):

Dateparser has support for quite a few [languages](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#supported-languages). You could parse the weekday to a datetime object then determine the next possible date available.

-- Edit --

```
 from dateparser import parse

 parse('Onsdag').isoweekday()  # 3
```

Now that you have the iso weekday, you can find the next possible date. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558535/find-the-date-for-the-first-monday-after-a-given-a-date) to see how.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `locale` aliases are platform specific and case sensitive. I've windows. So locale will be `sv_SE`.

You can use [babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/index.html) for date/time conversion and is much more comprehensive than native `locale` module.

> Babel is an integrated collection of utilities that assist in internationalizing and localizing Python applications, with an emphasis on web-based applications.

Which can be installed as:
`pip install Babel`

Once installed, we can use `format_date` , `format_datetime` , `format_time` utilities to format one language date , time to other.

You can use these utilities to convert date/time data between English and Swedish.

```
>>>import datetime
>>>from babel.dates import format_date, format_datetime, format_time

#Here we get current date time in an datetime object
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 31, 9, 46, 32, 650000)

#We format datetime object to english using babel
>>> format_date(now, locale='en')
u'Oct 31, 2017'

#We format datetime object to sweedish using babel
>>> format_date(now, locale='sv_SE')
u'31 okt. 2017'
>>>
```

Comment: babel is great but it works the other way round vs. the problem I described. I needed to build a date object first which 4d11 solves with his answer.