# How to set a get the date of the day of the week?

Tags: python, date

Basically what i want is to have the day of the week's date after saying next week or similar format and i though i found what i need in here:

[Find the date for the first Monday after a given a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558535/find-the-date-for-the-first-monday-after-a-given-a-date)

However testing the code proved it's giving somewhat answers i'd want differently :

```
import datetime
def next_weekday(d, weekday):
    days_ahead = weekday - d.weekday()
    if days_ahead <= 0: # Target day already happened this week
        days_ahead += 7
    return d + datetime.timedelta(days_ahead)

d = datetime.date(2017, 11, 30)
next_monday = next_weekday(d, 0) # 0 = Monday, 1=Tuesday, 2=Wednesday...
print(next_monday)
```

It worked as expected to give the date correctly for `next_weekday(d,0)`, 1,2,3 then for `next_weekday(d,4)` i get `2017-12-01` which my system interprets as faulty because `this friday` equate `2017-12-01` while `next friday` equates `2017-12-08` same for saturday and Sunday, so basically what i want if the day of the week we're seeking is still in the same week to give the date of that day for the week after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just always add 7 to `days_ahead` rather than only when the 
*"Target day has already happend this week"* to get a day in next week every time:

```
import datetime

def next_weekday(d, weekday):
  days_ahead = weekday - d.weekday() + 7
  return d + datetime.timedelta(days_ahead)

d = datetime.date(2017, 11, 30)
next_friday = next_weekday(d, 4)
print(next_friday) # 2017-12-08 which is next week rather than the friday this week: 2017-12-01
```

Comment: My bad, works just fine for this example, i'll test it for a couple of test cases and accept it if it works, thanks.