# Django - Add Nearest Monday to Queryset

Tags: django

I have an `Order` model like so:

```
class Order(models.Model):

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

An order can be created at any time, but all orders get shipped out on the following Monday.

How can I add an extra field to my orders queryset called `assembly_date` that reflects the next Monday (date the order should be shipped)?

I tried creating a custom `OrderManager` like so, but am not sure how to correctly set the `assembly_date`:

```
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper, DateField
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeekDay

class OrderManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(): 
    
        # need help with logic here:
        return self.super().get_queryset().annotate(
            assembly_date = ExpressionWrapper(
                F("created_at") - ExtractWeekDay("created_at"),
                output_field = DateField(),
            )
        )
```

But this operation results in the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone - double precision
LINE 1: ...E NULL END) * 2628000.0) * INTERVAL '1 seconds')) - EXTRACT(...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Keep in mind, I want to be able to filter all orders based on their assembly_date.

Comment: So for sunday it is the next day, right?

Comment: Correct and if it's a Monday then the `assembly_date` should be the same as the `created_at` date.

Comment: Use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractWeekDay and subtract it from date

Comment: Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558535/find-the-date-for-the-first-monday-after-a-given-a-date

Comment: maybe can use ```date.isoweekday``` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I am still stuck - I've tried some of the methods recommended in these comments. Above, my edited answer shows the error I'm running into presently.

Comment: if yo open to having another field in your model as ```assembly_date```, it will be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to dynamically generate `timedelta` inside of `annotate`. But as far as I know, there is no way you can apply `isoweekday()` to a datetimefield inside of `annotate`.

You can have another field as `assembly_date` in your model, and use it directly to query.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

class Order(models.Model):

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(...)
    assembly_date = models.DateTimeField(...)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       weekday = self.created_at.isoweekday() # 1 is Monday, 2 is Tuesday.
       daysdiff = 8 - weekday
       self.assembly_date = self.created_at + timedelta(days= daysdiff)
       super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```