# How do I get the next X day of the week

Tags: python, datetime, weekday

So I have this `function` that retrieve the `date` from given days from today:

```
def get_date_from_today(d):
    tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=d)
    return tomorrow.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

How do I get for example the date of the next `Thursday` ?

If today if `Thursday` I want to get the current `date` and if not I want to closest `Thursday` date

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6558535/10197418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `.isoweekday()` (Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7) you get the weekday as an integer. From there calculate the difference beetween today and the desired weekday.
If the difference is 0 the weekday is today. If `difference < 0` the neareast is in the past so add 7 to it. Else just add the difference.

```
def get_date_from_today(d):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    weekday = d-today.isoweekday()
    if weekday == 0:
        return today.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
    else:
        return (today + datetime.timedelta(days=weekday+7 if weekday < 0 else weekday)).strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

Note that in this solution your function parameter `d` is now your desired weekday as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

This code returns the next Thursday:

```
def get_next_thursday(year, month, day):
weekday = datetime(year, month, day).weekday()
if weekday == 3:
    return datetime(year, month, day)
if weekday > 3:
    return datetime(year, month, day) + timedelta(10 - weekday)
return datetime(year, month, day) + timedelta(3 - weekday)
```

Driver Code:

```
print(get_next_thursday(2023, 1, 16))
```